# I n.indexOf is not a function error when i try to reload the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

i'm using firestore to get some data from the database and everything work fine when i move bettwen pages but when i try to reload the page i get an error

```
  const { data } = useContext(SelectedChatContext);
  const [Chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  console.log(data);
  const combaindId =
    auth?.currentUser?.uid > data.uuid
      ? auth?.currentUser?.uid + data.uuid
      : data.uuid + auth?.currentUser?.uid;

  const getAllDataFromFireBase = () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "chats", combaindId);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        setChats(doc.data());
      } else {
        setChats([]);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe; // return a function to clean up the listener
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = getAllDataFromFireBase();
    return () => unsubscribe(); // clean up the listener when the component unmounts
  }, [data]);
```